# How to create a text file in Ruby owned by root?

Tags: ruby, file, unix

It's trivially easy in Ruby to create a text file as the current user using `File.write`, but if I want the file to be owned by root, it becomes a lot more complicated.

I realize that I could run the Ruby script itself with `sudo` but would prefer not to do that.

How can I do this?

Comment: Forget ruby for a moment -- are you able to `chown root <filename>`? Presumable no, you need `sudo chown root <filename>` (and possibly enter a password); and this will only work if you are in the `sudoers` file. If a ruby script - or any script for that matter - were able to bypass this security policy, then it would be a huge vulnerability in unix systems.

Comment: So one way or another, *somewhere* along the line you're going to need `sudo` permission. This could be at a the initial command line call, or invoked later on in the script, or (with extreme caution) you could set the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) in the permission. But you cannot change a file owner to `root` without superuser permissions having been granted somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I realize that I need to use `sudo`. My point was that I did not want the entire script to be run with sudo, just the specific commands that needed it. The answer below is my own and illustrates what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to create or open the file as root (which I believe is impossible if the Ruby script has been started as a nonroot user), the file can be created as the current user first and then have its ownership and permissions changed.

As a practical matter it probably makes sense to use Ruby's `Tempfile` functionality to create the initial file, since it eliminates the need to determine a unique filename and will not require that the current directory be writable. Here is the code I came up with (it's also posted at https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/2c6f53351bf9cdb0bbbfd3f7f97dc91c). The module is defined and the call to it is on the last line. I've made some assumptions, e.g. that the file should be world readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'tempfile'

module SudoFileWriter

  module_function

  # Writes passed text to a temp file.
  # @return the filespec of the temp file.
  def write_to_temp_file(text)
    filespec = nil
    Tempfile.open do |file|
      file.write(text)
      filespec = file.path
    end
    filespec
  end


  def write_to_root_file(filespec, text)
    temp_filespec = write_to_temp_file(text)
    commands = [
        "sudo chown root:wheel #{temp_filespec}",
        "sudo mv #{temp_filespec} #{filespec}",
        "sudo chmod +r #{filespec}"
    ]
    puts "Running commands for file #{filespec}:\n\n"; puts commands
    `#{commands.join(' && ')}`
  end


  def call(filespec, object_to_write)
    write_to_root_file(filespec, object_to_write.to_s)
  end
end

# .() is shorthand for .call().
# `module_function` above results in all methods being both module level
# and instance level methods, so we can call directly on the module object.

SudoFileWriter.('root-owned-file.txt', "The time is now #{Time.now}.\n")
```

Output looks like this:

```
Running commands for file root-owned-file.txt:

sudo chown root:wheel /var/folders/bk/8y3jvjs53qs9wlqtpzqq6_080000gn/T/20180810-9981-124bxcl
sudo mv /var/folders/bk/8y3jvjs53qs9wlqtpzqq6_080000gn/T/20180810-9981-124bxcl root-owned-file.txt
sudo chmod +r root-owned-file.txt
Password:
The time is now 2018-08-10 16:01:05 +0700.
```